# Dynamic React navbar from an object

Tags: reactjs, object, react-router, navbar, react-router-dom

I am doing a personal `React.js` project. I want to dynamically do the navbar from an API that I am using. I want to display links to the list of films. The problem is that the [API](https://www.swapi.tech/) brings an object and I do not know how to do the code. This is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {  BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Navbar = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("https://www.swapi.tech/api/films/");
        const json = await res.json();
        setResult(json.result);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <>
        <BrowserRouter>
        {result.map((value, key) =>  {
            <Link />
        })}
        </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

Maybe there is another way to do it than dynamically.
Also, I have another component with a rendered list of the films. Ideally I would like to be able to click in each item of that list and go to a new page with the description of it. The links of the navbar would go to the same pages.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: By dynamic navbar do you mean you want to generate links from the API response? What are you trying to link to? Where are you rendering routes to link to?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese I just updated the post. I  have another component with a rendered list of the films. Ideally I would like to be able to click in each item of that list and go to a new page with the description of it. The links of the navbar would go to the same pages.

Comment: So if you've another component rendering a list of the movies, how are those rendering a link to each movie? Can we see that component's code? Does *that* other component fetch the same data the `Navbar` does? Do you have any routes you are trying to link to? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method to deal with your API response

```
 <BrowserRouter>
   {result.map((value) => (
      <Link to={value._id}>{value.description}</Link>
    ))}
  </BrowserRouter>
```